# How to check if all nodes in a graph are reachable from all other nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve this question:

> There are n cities and m flight connections. Your task is to check if
>   you can travel from any city to any other city using the available
>   flights.
>
> Input
>
> The first input line has two integers n and m: the number of cities
>   and flights. The cities are numbered 1,2,…,n.
>
> After this, there are m lines describing the flights. Each line has
>   two integers a and b: there is a flight from city a to city b. All
>   flights are one-way flights.

My approach is to do a dfs rooted at every node, keep track of all nodes we've visited. Then check if we have visited all nodes. This runs in n^2 though. This times out though.

Could someone guide me through a more optiomal algorithm?

Comment: You've included the tag [tag:connected-components] (which, ironically, is not about graph components). Did you not find any algorithms when you searched using this term?

Comment: You can store some information that might be useful, for example: if you know you can reach some set of nodes from node `u`, if you are in a node `v` and you can reach `u`, you know that `v` can also reach that same set. This should give you some extra time to do more dfss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your criterion that every node is reachable from every other node is equivalent to testing whether the number of [strongly connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) in the graph is 1.

There are efficient well-known algorithms for finding the strongly connected components of a graph, such as [Kosaraju's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosaraju%27s_algorithm) and [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm), which both run in O(*n* + *m*) time on a graph with *n* nodes and *m* edges.